# Backbone.model, how should I modify the get method

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

Using Backbone.model, I would like to change the get method in order to get an object when I do not pass parameter to `get method`... see the following example:

```
Task = Backbone.Model.extend({});
task = new Task({
    id: 2, 
    name: "taskName"
});

task.get("id"); // 2 // ***** ok ******
task.get("name"); // "taskName" // ***** ok ******
task.get(); // undefined // ******* it should be {id: 2, name: "taskName"} *****
```

Comment: Any reason not to use `task.attributes`?

Comment: Well this is not dumb at all, get() could return the whole object. It seems logicall.

Comment: I think one should try the best to write as less as possible and make the things more obvious.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could override `Model().get()`, as noted in the documentation:

- http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Model-extend

E.g.

```
Task = Backbone.Model.extend({
    get: function(attribute){
        if(typeof attribute  === "undefined"){
             return this.attributes;
             // Or, assuming you’ve also got json2.js available:
             // return this.toJSON();
        }
        else {
            return Backbone.Model.prototype.set.call(this, attribute);
        }
    }
});
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/TByhD/2/)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `task.attributes` to do this. [From the documentation](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Model-attributes):

> The **attributes** property is the internal hash containing the model's state.

[Here's a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/TByhD/).